# Aptana Studio 3 - Update authentication failed

Tags: aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 standalone v3.4.2 for the first time yesterday. Immediately upon first launch I was prompted for a username and password: "Please provide login details for download.aptana.com". Is this intentional? I haven't found any place where you can create an account in the app or on the website. I hit cancel at the login box and then I get "'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem. Authentication failed for http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/." If I try to access that URL directly in my browser I get an XML dump:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>19EE077C70E56155</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        f4PBxyf0Jh2iHwaOBUeW7U/c4LbqkBnxdz9z8Bh3KbuGJ9rkak3jvHZ1gfxTl4ms
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: I'm getting this response as well! I'm behind a (Very) strict webFilter at work, so I suspected that at first, but after getting it unblocked I got the above XML response. Then, trying to access http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio3/3.4.2.201308081736/site.xml ended up being blocked as well. Still no resolution.